# Access an enum using an index in C

Tags: c, enums, indexing

Consider:

```
enum Test
{
    a = 3,
    b = 7,
    c = 1
};
```

I want to access the enum using an index. Something like this:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    doSomething((Test)i);
```

How can I do something like this, where I will be able to access the enum using an index, though the members of the enum have different values?

Comment: Why do you post the same exact question twice?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183323/working-with-enums-in-c-c/10183382#comment13070000_10183382

Comment: the cast, if it would make sense (and it doesn't) should be `enum Test`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the best you can do:

```
enum Test { a = 3, b = 7, c = 1, LAST = -1 };
static const enum Test Test_map[] = { a, b, c, LAST };

for (int i = 0; Test_map[i] != LAST; i++)
    doSomething(Test_map[i]);
```

You have to maintain the mapping yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. A C enum is not much more than a bunch of constants. There's no type-safety or reflection that you might get in a C# or Java `enum`.

Answer (score 3):

Your question demonstrates you don't really understand what an enum is for.

It is not something that can be indexed, nor is there ever any reason to. What you have defined is actually just 3 constants named `a`, `b`, and `c`, whose values are `3`, `7`, and `1` respectively.

Answer (score 3):

As someone else mentioned, this is not the purpose of an enum. In order to do what you are asking, you can simply use an array:

```
#define a 3
#define b 7
#define c 1

int array[3] = { a, b, c };
int i;

for( i = 0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); i++ ) {
    doSomething( array[i] );
}
```

Comment: Yes, but unlike an enum, you have to specify a type for the values. You also have to make sure the index won’t be higher than the number of cells.